# Sharepoint Online PowerShell script to enumerate all sites and subsites and users

Tags: powershell, online

I have this task to iterate through a tenant, listing each site and subsite and 
its users (if possible with permissions).
I've seen a script that says to do that but it does not list the subsites and the users that are there.
The script that I am referring is :

Script that allows to get all the users for all the Site Collections in a SharePoint Online Tenant
Required Parameters:

```
-> $sUserName: User Name to connect to the SharePoint Admin Center. 

-> $sMessage: Message to show in the user credentials prompt.  
-> $sSPOAdminCenterUrl: SharePoint Admin Center Url



$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
```

Definition of the function that gets all the site collections information in a SharePoint Online tenant

```
function Get-SPOUsersAllSiteCollections
{
    param ($sUserName,$sMessage)
    try
    {    
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green
        Write-Host "Getting the information for all the site colletions in the Office 365 tenant" -foregroundcolor Green
        Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------"  -foregroundcolor Green
        #$msolcred = get-credential -UserName $sUserName -Message $sMessage
        #Connect-SPOService -Url $sSPOAdminCenterUrl -Credential $msolcred
        $spoSites=Get-SPOSite | Select *
        foreach($spoSite in $spoSites)
        {
            Write-Host "Users for " $spoSite.Url -foregroundcolor Blue
            Get-SPOUser -Site $spoSite.Url
            Write-Host
        }        
    }
    catch [System.Exception]
    {
        write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString()   
    }    
}

#Connection to Office 365
$sUserName="<YourOffice365Account>"
$sMessage="Introduce your SPO Credentials"
$sSPOAdminCenterUrl="https://<YourDomain>-admin.sharepoint.com/"

Get-SPOUsersAllSiteCollections -sUserName $sUserName -sMessage $sMessage
```

the link is :
https://github.com/CompartiMOSS/SharePoint-PowerShell/blob/master/Office%20365/PS_Get_SPOUsers_AllSiteCollections.ps1

What I'm referring to 'each subsite' is :

I may have a site ('Joe') like this:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Joe/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

and a subsite, under 'Joe' like this:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/Joe/SubSiteJoe/SitePages/Home.aspx
```

The script shows the 'Joe' site and the users, but not the 'SubSiteJoe' under it.

Any ideas if this is possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with ShareGate Permission Matrix report in O365 v8.3.4 and I have to say its buggy and untrustworthy. It's better to use a powershell script!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ShareGate licens inhouse this sounds like the Permission Matrix report. I guess once you have this report you will have rearrange permissions, move sites and so on. In that case ih really pays off to look at one of the available tools , like ShareGate or Metalogix. ( I don't get kickbacks or anything like it, I just like NOT to reinvent the wheel)

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have  a ShareGate license for this matrix. I was hoping that maybe it was possible to do this with PowerShell.  Thanks

Comment: Indeed it is, just the same way as ShareGate did it, but it takes time and lots of trial and error to replicate a commercial product